# php startup error Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pcntl.so'

Tags: linux, debian, php

After searching for hours to solve my problem and found nothing helpful I ask my first question here.

I want to compile and install **php 5.3.17 cli** with **pcntl extension enabled** on a Debian server.
The installation was successfull but when I start php cli, the following error is displayed:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'pcntl.so' in Unknown\
on line 0
```

The following configure is used:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/share' '--datadir=/usr/share/php' '--bindir=/usr/bin' 
'--libdir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' 
'--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/cli' '--disable-cgi' '--enable-bcmath' 
'-- enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-pcntl'
'--enable-sigchild' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' 
'--enable-sysvshm' '--with-mysql' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-kerberos'
```

In the php.ini following options are set:

```
extension_dir=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/
extension=pcntl.so
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem now, with some help from this post [stackoverflow answer how-to-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230255/how-to-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp).

First I switched to the source directory of the pcntl extension `/src/php-5.3.17-cli/ext/pcntl`. 
 
There I ran the following commands in the shell:

```
phpize
./configure
make
```

Then the extension was created at `/src/php-5.3.17-cli/ext/pcntl/modules` and I copied it in the right directory with `cp /src/php-5.3.17-cli/ext/pcntl/module/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php5/20090626/`.

Now the extension works for my php-cli installation. 
Thank you @terdon for your answer it pushed me a bit in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a file called `pcntl.so` in the `modules` subdirectory of the directory where you built php. Copy that to `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/` :

```
sudo cp PHP_BUILD_DIR/modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php5/20090626/
```

Obviously, change `PHP_BUILD_DIR` to the directory where you compiled php.

Comment: After finishing the build of php the `pcntl.so` extension was created at `/usr/share/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/` and I copied it to `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/`.  

When the `pcntl.so` file is not in the directory the following error message occurse:

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pcntl.so' -
usr/lib/php5/20090626/pcntl.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

So I think the file is at the right place.